# An efficient Pythonic way of mapping values?

Tags: python

I have some values to remap based on there being two ways to specify a rule.  The simple `if` / `else` method appears the more efficient variant, but I wonder if there is an equally as efficient but more pythonic approach?

```
 if mod == "I": mod = "+"
 elif mod == "E": mod = "-"
 elif mod == "D": mod = ":"
 elif mod == "M": mod = "."
```

Not so efficient mapping approach:

```
 mod = { "I":"+", "E":"-", "D":":", "M":"." }.get(mod, mod)
```

Comment: Efficient in what sense? What is inefficient about the approach you came up with (which is quite Pythonic)?

Comment: I agree with Thijs: if you store the dict as a separate reference, you only need construct it once and use it from that point on.

Comment: I’d say both approaches are equally pythonic.

Comment: Well, with the hash, there is stack modification through the `get` function call, then another internal call to the hashing algorithm to hash the one character I pass in, before evaluating if the key matches anything in the table and returning the matched entry or the default I passed in.  With the `if` and `else` approach, it's a simple string comparison that compares one byte each time.  But it just looks a bit amateurish.  Nothing like a good switch statement to clean things up.

Comment: I smell premature optimization. Python's `dict` is crazy fast. If the things you mention really matter (measure!), Python might not be the tool for the job.

Comment: I did measure: `if_else took 12474 ms for 100000 operations,
translation_table took 81650 ms for 100000 operations,
dict_lookup took 66385 ms for 100000 operations`

Comment: This is not a great way of doing timing on Python. Have a look at `timeit`. I found that `dict` and `if_else` perform about the same, depending on the amount of "luck" `if_else` has for its input. The fastest thing I could find so far is: `translate_mod = {"I":"+", "E":"-", "D":":", "M":"." }.get` which is then callable. It consistently performs about 15% better than `if_else`. The reasons it's faster, is that you have one lookup (the dot) less, and of course that the `dict` is created only once.

Comment: You're right, the best was to time something is using `time`.  It will tell you how much CPU time something costs.  Profiling using language specific tools is always bad, since the language will almost certainly optimise the profiling tool itself.  It's better just to ask the kernel how long something took.

Answer (score 2):

Mapping will result in an O(1) lookup. Conditionals will result in O(N). Of course, there's the additional function call in your map implementation to take into account as well if you want to get all nit-picky about it.

Rather than theorizing, [I ran a quick benchmark](https://gist.github.com/demianbrecht/7047617). The results (removing the `get` call and strictly using an array accessor, the results:

```
   2 function calls in 0.025 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.025    0.025    0.025    0.025 {range}


   4 function calls in 0.035 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.035    0.018    0.035    0.018 {range}
```

Now admittedly, this only uses the cases given. My assumption is that if runtime of the conditionals will increase linearly with the number of cases, while the map lookup will remain constant.

Comment: How would conditionals result in anything *other* than `O(N)`? Why do you say *worst case*?

Comment: I know, the map solution was just an example of what I consider to be something more pythonic.  I wasn't actually asking which of the two solutions I provided is the best choice.

Comment: @kojiro: Guess that's a little redundant, fixed.

Comment: @kojiro The best case scenario for minor if-else's is an O(0). You try the first thing and are correct.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: Arguably however, O-notation should reflect the worst case complexity of the algorithm. Therefore, O(N) is the running time of the conditional version.

Comment: @DemianBrecht SOrry, I meant Omega, not O.

Comment: @cwallenpoole You mean Ω(1). Ω(0) is for code that doesn't run.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed and small number of cases, the `if-elif-else` approach is the fastest (and I can't see why it would be un-Pythonic); for a sufficiently large number of cases, a `dict` lookup will be better.

If the set of cases is dynamic, the `dict` approach is of course the only viable one.

Also, a third, non-orthodox approach, would be to use macro metaprogramming. This is not possible with vanilla python, however there are libraries e.g. https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy that allow you to do this in an (arguably) clean manner (most probably not approved by the Python community or Guido).

P.S. on second thought, the macro approach probably wouldn't work in Python as it would in Lisp in the case of most macro implementations for Python, which try to stick to the syntax of vanilla Python; i.e. generating an `if-elif-else` block from within a macro wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that a multi-level `if` statement generates a lot of byte code and is primarily evaluated at the Python level, while a dictionary access happens in the optimized C code of the interpreter. Also, the `if` statement requires an average of `n/2` comparisons if there are `n` possibilities: it has to check each possibility in order.

The moral of the story: `dicts` are probably fast enough, but when in doubt, profile to find your *real* bottleneck, not the one you suspect.

---

Compare:

```
def f(mod):
    if mod == "I": return "+"
    elif mod == "E": return "-"
    elif mod == "D": return ":"
    elif mod == "M": return "."

dis.dis(f)
  4           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (mod)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('I')
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 ('+')
             15 RETURN_VALUE

  5     >>   16 LOAD_FAST                0 (mod)
             19 LOAD_CONST               3 ('E')
             22 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             25 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       32
             28 LOAD_CONST               4 ('-')
             31 RETURN_VALUE

  6     >>   32 LOAD_FAST                0 (mod)
             35 LOAD_CONST               5 ('D')
             38 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             41 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       48
             44 LOAD_CONST               6 (':')
             47 RETURN_VALUE

  7     >>   48 LOAD_FAST                0 (mod)
             51 LOAD_CONST               7 ('M')
             54 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             57 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       64
             60 LOAD_CONST               8 ('.')
             63 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   64 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             67 RETURN_VALUE


d={"I": "+", "E": "-", "D": ":", "M": "."}
def g(mod):
    return d.get(mod, mod)

12           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (d)
             3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (get)
             6 LOAD_FAST                0 (mod)
             9 LOAD_FAST                0 (mod)
            12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
            15 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

The string methods have a translation function available.   You have to build a translation table of 256 characters long.   Here is the code snippet I used:

```
translationTable = ' '*256
translationTable = translationTable[:68]+':'+translationTable[69:] # D to :
translationTable = translationTable[:69]+'-'+translationTable[70:] # E to -
translationTable = translationTable[:73]+'+'+translationTable[74:] # I to +
translationTable = translationTable[:77]+'.'+translationTable[78:] # M to .
print 'EIDM'.translate(translationTable)
```

Output:

```
-+:.
```

Comment: `from string import maketrans; translation_table = maketrans('IEDM', '+-:.')` - didn't think of it, but it is a very reasonable solution indeed. Not sure how it works under the hood, though; might be no faster than a `dict`.

Comment: Let me run some timings and I'll let you know.

Comment: `if_else took 12474 ms for 100000 operations,
translation_table took 81650 ms for 100000 operations,
dict_lookup took 66385 ms for 100000 operations`

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer as such, but a lot of the comments centred on performance, since I did ask.  So I ran some performance tests on the answers so far:

```
from datetime import datetime
from string import maketrans
tr_table = maketrans('IEDM', '+-:.')
dictionary = { "I":"+", "E":"-", "D":":", "M":"." }
if_else_val = "E"

N_OPS = 100000

now = datetime.now

def time(func):
    s = now()
    func()
    print "%s took %d ms for %d operations" % (func.__name__, (now() - s).microseconds, N_OPS)

def translation_table():
    for i in xrange(N_OPS):
        "I".translate(tr_table)
        "E".translate(tr_table)
        "D".translate(tr_table)
        "M".translate(tr_table)

def dict_lookup():
    for i in xrange(N_OPS):
        dictionary.get("I")
        dictionary.get("E")
        dictionary.get("D")
        dictionary.get("M")

def if_else():
    for i in xrange(N_OPS):
        if if_else_val == "I": pass
        elif if_else_val == "E": pass
        elif if_else_val == "D": pass
        elif if_else_val == "M": pass

time(if_else)
time(translation_table)
time(dict_lookup)
```

Here are the results:

```
if_else took 12474 ms for 100000 operations
translation_table took 81650 ms for 100000 operations
dict_lookup took 66385 ms for 100000 operations
```

Comment: This is not a great way of doing timing on Python. Have a look at `timeit`.

Comment: @Craig: check out IPython and its `timeit` command.